# Want to Fill Text Box With Access Data

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-access

In C# I want to use access data to fill my textBox I Am using ADO.Net To connect to access.So far I've got this:

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(Price.constr);
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.Connection=con;
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from Table1";
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
```

Price.constr is my connection String.
I want to fill textBox1 with the data in the Price Column Where my row ID = 1.(For Example)

Comment: In this way you read ALL of Table1. If you want to read only one record you need to add a WHERE statement to your query. And if there is only one record use an OleDbDataReader instead of filling a DataTable through an adapter

Comment: @Steve I don't know the command to fill the text box i know it with dataGridView by selecting the row but i don't know how to do it without dataGridView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to read only one record from your table then there is no need to return the whole table and use an adapter to fill a datatable. You can simply ask the database to return just the record you are interested in.

```
string cmdText = "select * from Table1 WHERE ID = 1";
using(OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(Price.constr))
using(OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmdText, con))
{
    con.Open();
    using(OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if(reader.Read())
           textBox1.Text = reader["Price"].ToString();
        else
           textBox1.Text = "No record found";
    }
}
```

I have enclose the connection, command and reader in an using statement because these are disposable objects and it is a good practice to destroy them when you have finished to use them. (In particular the connection could cause problems if you don't dispose it)

Notice also that I have used the constant 1 to retrieve the record. I bet that you want this to be dynamic and in this case I suggest you to look at how to PARAMETRIZE your queries. (Don't do string concatenations)

Comment: No there isn't any error message i put this thing that you wrote in the form load function but it doesn't put the data in the textbox

Comment: It works, i took another look, I made a little mistake from myself the code is ok , thanks man. Accepted the answer